# Performance difference for STRING(MAX)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Is there a performance penalty (or improvement) for using `STRING(MAX)` instead of some fixed limit like `STRING(256)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope. `STRING(MAX)` is treated exactly the same as strings of limited length under-the-hood. Same applies for `BYTES(MAX)`. So there is no performance difference.

The main reason to use a fixed limit is if there are logical constraints you want to enforce in your schema. For example: if you are using a `STRING` to store 2-letter country codes, then you might want to using `STRING(2)`.

Note that, according to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/schema-updates#supported_schema_updatesw), you can always change the length limit for a string, except with one caveat:

- *Supported Schema Updates*: Increase or decrease the length limit for a
  `STRING` or `BYTES` type (including to `MAX`), unless it is a primary 
  key column inherited by one or more child tables.

Comment: Do you know what that MAX is?

Comment: I believe the answer is 10MiB (~10M bytes). Per: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/data-types#string_type "The maximum size of a column value is 10MiB, which applies to scalar and array types."

Comment: Duh, I was looking everywhere for that! Assumed it would be lower on the docs haha